# How do I implement a left view controller in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, c

One of my friends is building an app and needs some help implementing a slide-out menu, kinda like what Slack or GroupMe has. He asked me since I have some experience with C. I found [this open-source code](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), but the guides attached are either outdated or use methods I can't, as the app doesn't have a storyboard.main and is written in C. I was hoping someone either help me with using this without using Storyboard.main, or provide another implementation of the slide-out menu that I could incorporate into a C-built app.

Comment: If the slide-out menu must be a view controller, then you need to implement a container view controller that displays the content-view-controller and the slide-out-menu-view-controller. The other option, as Aderis mentioned, is to make the slide-out menu a UIView that you animate onto the screen with the `UIView animateWithDuration` method.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a regular UIView for the menu and just have it offscreen until it is needed.

Comment: I'm pretty new to iOS - only reason my friend asked is because I'm the only one he knows who can also code in C lol. Is there a guide or link you'd recommend for doing what you suggested?

Comment: @dizfunctions For Objective-C, try http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/uiview-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-in-ios-5-a-5-star-rating-view I would also take a look at the docs for UIView.

Comment: Sweet! I'll check this out :D

Comment: Hey Aderis, will the procedures for iOS 5 be the same as iOS 8? Or should I not be worried about that?

Comment: They should all be the same. Functions get deprecated and some get added (rarely), but that is the extent of any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) library. It's very flexible in layout and easy for using.

Comment: This looks great! I'll definitely check it out when I get home from work.